# Bluebird: promisify xhr request

Tags: javascript, promise

I use bluebird promises. I want to promisify my requests from communication layer:

***`Utils.js`***

```
//Question: is there more beautiful way to do that?
promisifyXMLHttpRequest(xhr, timeout = 0, timeoutCallback = _.noop, responseHandler = response => JSON.parse(response).data) {
    const requestPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    resolve(responseHandler(xhr.responseText));
                } else {
                    reject(xhr.statusText);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            reject(xhr.statusText);
        };
    });

    if (timeout) {
        requestPromise.timeout(timeout)
            .catch(TimeoutError, error => {
                timeoutCallback(error);
            });
    }

    return requestPromise;
}
```

***`Communication`***

```
_sendRequest(body, sessionId, timeout, timeoutCallback, responseHandler) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', SOME_URL, true);
    if (sessionId) xhr.setRequestHeader('swarm-session', sessionId);
    const requestPromise = Utils.promisifyXMLHttpRequest(xhr, timeout, timeoutCallback, responseHandler);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
    return requestPromise;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const requestPromise = Utils.promisifyXMLHttpRequest(xhr, timeout, timeoutCallback, responseHandler);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
return requestPromise;

// to something like

return myLib.post(...)
```

To start, I suggest you just fire the request immediately and return a promise. I don't see a reason why you'd separate the creation of the XHR from the moment it fires given the code you provided.

```
const requestPromise = Utils.promisifyXMLHttpRequest(xhr, timeout, timeoutCallback, responseHandler);
```

I don't understand why you are handing over callbacks when you can simply attach `then` and `catch` to the returned promise. The purpose of promises is to have an object to which you can listen for events related to an async operation.

I also don't understand why you'd separate the XHR object creation from the code that attaches all the handlers. I suggest you just moving everything related to xhr creation into one function. This includes creating the xhr, the promise, adding the headers.

```
if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    ...

// to

if(xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
if(xhr.readyState === 200) resolve(...);
else reject(...);
```

Just twisting the logic to avoid the extra nesting. If the `onload` isn't ready, we just `return` early. No harm done. Otherwise, it is ready and we either do a `resolve` or `reject`. `if` statements can do no-bracket bodies, but I suggest to use them only when they're short, readable and only one line.

Simplifying your code, it should be like this. `post` creates your xhr, sends it and returns a promise. All `_sendRequest` has to be concerned about is preparing and providing `post` the data needed to send out the request, and attaching callbacks depending on what happens to that promise.

```
function post(url, headers, body, timeout){
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if(xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
      if(xhr.status === 200) resolve(xhr.responseText);
      else reject(xhr.statusText);
    }
    xhr.onerror = () => {
      reject(xhr.statusText);
    };
  });

  Object.keys(headers).forEach(key => {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
  });

  if(timeout) promise.timeout(timeout);

  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
  return promise;
}

_sendRequest(body, sessionId, timeout, timeoutCallback, responseHandler){
  var headers = {}
  if(sessionId) headers['swarm-session'] = sessionId;

  return post(SOME_URL, headers, body, timeout)
    .then(responseHandler)
    .catch(timeoutCallback);
}
```

Comment: thanks for nice answer. Just faced with the next function `Promise.promisify` http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html. But spec says only about node functions. Is there an ability to od something like `Promise.promisify(xhr.send)`?

Comment: @NickoleAbs It's possible, but `send` [doesn't conform to the convention](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/264d5c5ba61bb5a33b9134be372d2b01902d4980/API.md#promisepromisifyfunction-nodefunction--dynamic-receiver---function). You can wrap the entire mechanism into a function that does such. But then, there's little point to wrapping as you can simply just create, resolve and reject the promise yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This seems quite fine to me.
One thing that pops to mind is that I lose the ability to see the status code of the error as you only reject with the message text. I would wrap that in an object where the statuscode is also exposed.